# preload youtube video iframe for smoother jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, youtube, slidedown

I have a number of links to youtube video iframes which appear in a popup window using jQuery slideDown by passing the Youtube href as shown below. Works fine, but the effect is jarring because the Youtube img doesn't 'respect' the jQuery slideDown and display smoothly. Eg.

http://jchmusic.com/videos

...just click on any of the 4 img links.

Is there a way to somehow 'preload' the content of the Youtube iFrame (or other technique) so that the slideDown illusion is better? (BTW: I already tried appending separate nodes rather than all one big string as below and it had no effect.)

```
jQuery('ul.slideshow a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();          
    var pNum = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#modalpopup #inside').empty();          
    jQuery('#modalpopup #inside').append('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + pNum + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    iH = jQuery(document).height();
jQuery('#overlay').height(iH - 112).fadeTo( 'slow', .2 );
    jQuery('#modalpopup').slideDown(1000);
});
```

TIA,

---JC

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I have a page animation where pages fly in from the side of the browser, and pages with youtube videos make the effect kind of jarring. It would be nice to find a way to preload the youtube iframe similar to how I preload all the images so the transition is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `setTimeout`

```
jQuery('ul.slideshow a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pNum = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#modalpopup #inside').empty();
    jQuery('#modalpopup #inside').append('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + pNum + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    setTimeout(function() {
        iH = jQuery(document).height();
        jQuery('#overlay').height(iH - 112).fadeTo('slow', .2);
        jQuery('#modalpopup').slideDown(1000);
    }, 1200);
});​
```

Comment: Nope. All that does is make the user wonder why they have to wait for something to happen. What I need is some way (and this will sound totally ignorant) to preload the youtube image into a 'screen buffer' -before- the click.. similar to the preload img trick. But I have no idea how to do this in js.